# NPOI Format Number As Text

Tags: vb.net, excel, format, npoi

I'm trying to generate a excel file using VB in visual studio 2010, using the NPOI library.
I ran into the issue where the data inserted are format incorrectly.

For example, I have a user id `"0001"`, and I'm trying to inserted into excel.
In the output excel file, the cell says `"1"` which is incorrect. I looked at the format and it already says "Text" and not "General".

How can I go about inserting `"0001"` correctly instead of `"1"`?

I tried this and it's no making any changes

```
myStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("text")
```

I tried `"@"` as well and also doesn't make any changes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try add single quote before the text, for example, '1

Comment: one of the option you can try is prefix single quote for data when writing it for excel cell of file  like '0001.

Comment: Hi, I get the same issue. I did not see a solution to this problem. Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the CellType to String if you don't already.

```
cellType = NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.String;
var cell=currentRow.CreateCell(i, cellType);
```

Or in C# try:

```
cell.SetCellType(NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.String);
```

Comment: In C# is `cell.SetCellType(NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.String);` Thanks for inspiring!